# how can I fix the issue with the fixed aside menu?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-position

well , I want to create an fixed aside menu bar , and navbar fixed top , but when I scroll down. it should be scrolled the main content, but however scroll down together with aside menu , how can I fix it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link href="../../../assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="../../../assets/css/theme3.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top fixed">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="../navbar/">Default</a></li>
                <li><a href="../navbar-static-top/">Static top</a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="./">Fixed top <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
              </ul>
            </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
          </div>
        </nav>

    <div class="container-fluid">

          <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">

             <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebar" role="navigation">

                <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                  <li class="active"><a href="#">Overview</a></li>
                  <li><a href="http://bootstrapzero.com" target="_ext">Themes</a></li>
                  <li><a href="http://bootstrap.theme.cards" target="_ext">Analytics</a></li>
                  <li><a href="https://wrapbootstrap.com?ref=skelly" target="_ext">Export</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                  <li><a href="">Nav item</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Nav item again</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">One more nav</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Another nav item</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">More navigation</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                  <li><a href="">Nav item again</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">One more nav</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Another nav item</a></li>
                </ul>

            </div><!--/span-->

            <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-10 main">

              <!--toggle sidebar button-->
              <p class="visible-xs">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="offcanvas"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></button>
              </p>

              <h1 class="page-header">
                Dashboard
                <p class="lead">(<a href="http://www.bootply.com/128936">with off-canvas sidebar</a>)</p>
              </h1>

              <div class="row placeholders">
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 placeholder text-center">
                  <img src="//placehold.it/200/6666ff/fff" class="center-block img-responsive img-circle" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail">
                  <h4>Label</h4>
                  <span class="text-muted">Something else</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 placeholder text-center">
                  <img src="//placehold.it/200/66ff66/fff" class="center-block img-responsive img-circle" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail">
                  <h4>Label</h4>
                  <span class="text-muted">Something else</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 placeholder text-center">
                  <img src="//placehold.it/200/6666ff/fff" class="center-block img-responsive img-circle" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail">
                  <h4>Label</h4>
                  <span class="text-muted">Something else</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 placeholder text-center">
                  <img src="//placehold.it/200/66ff66/fff" class="center-block img-responsive img-circle" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail">
                  <h4>Label</h4>
                  <span class="text-muted">Something else</span>
                </div>
              </div>

              <hr>

              <h2 class="sub-header">Section title</h2>
              <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-striped">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>#</th>
                      <th>Header</th>
                      <th>Header</th>
                      <th>Header</th>
                      <th>Header</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td>1,001</td>
                      <td>Lorem</td>
                      <td>ipsum</td>
                      <td>dolor</td>
                      <td>sit</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>1,002</td>
                      <td>amet</td>
                      <td>consectetur</td>
                      <td>adipiscing</td>
                      <td>elit</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>1,003</td>
                      <td>Integer</td>
                      <td>nec</td>
                      <td>odio</td>
                      <td>Praesent</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>1,003</td>
                      <td>libero</td>
                      <td>Sed</td>
                      <td>cursus</td>
                      <td>ante</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>1,004</td>
                      <td>dapibus</td>
                      <td>diam</td>
                      <td>Sed</td>
                      <td>nisi</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>1,005</td>
                      <td>Nulla</td>
                      <td>quis</td>
                      <td>sem</td>
                      <td>at</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>1,006</td>
                      <td>nibh</td>
                      <td>elementum</td>
                      <td>imperdiet</td>
                      <td>Duis</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>1,007</td>
                      <td>sagittis</td>
                      <td>ipsum</td>
                      <td>Praesent</td>
                      <td>mauris</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>1,008</td>
                      <td>Fusce</td>
                      <td>nec</td>
                      <td>tellus</td>
                      <td>sed</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>1,009</td>
                      <td>augue</td>
                      <td>semper</td>
                      <td>porta</td>
                      <td>Mauris</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>1,010</td>
                      <td>massa</td>
                      <td>Vestibulum</td>
                      <td>lacinia</td>
                      <td>arcu</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>1,011</td>
                      <td>eget</td>
                      <td>nulla</td>
                      <td>Class</td>
                      <td>aptent</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>1,012</td>
                      <td>taciti</td>
                      <td>sociosqu</td>
                      <td>ad</td>
                      <td>litora</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>1,013</td>
                      <td>torquent</td>
                      <td>per</td>
                      <td>conubia</td>
                      <td>nostra</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>1,014</td>
                      <td>per</td>
                      <td>inceptos</td>
                      <td>himenaeos</td>
                      <td>Curabitur</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>1,015</td>
                      <td>sodales</td>
                      <td>ligula</td>
                      <td>in</td>
                      <td>libero</td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>

              <a href="http://www.bootply.com/gkTHCwjLO9">Get the Source Code</a> | <a href="http://bootstrap.theme.cards">More free Bootstrap themes</a>

          </div><!--/row-->
        </div>
    </div><!--/.container-->
          <script src="../../../assets/js/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../../../assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../../../assets/js/core3.min.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

css

```
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
footer {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

/*
 * Off Canvas
 * --------------------------------------------------
 */
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .row-offcanvas {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  }

  .row-offcanvas-left
  .sidebar-offcanvas {
    left: -33%;
  }

  .row-offcanvas-left.active {
    left: 33%;
  }

  .sidebar-offcanvas {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 33%;
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
}


/* Sidebar navigation */
.nav-sidebar {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}
.nav-sidebar > li > a {
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.nav-sidebar > .active > a {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #428bca;
}

/*
 * Main content
 */

.main {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .main {
    padding-right: 40px;
    padding-left: 40px;
  }
}
.main .page-header {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/476z83tn/1/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for a fixed sidebar with the content scroll.

Wrap with "main-content" div under "main" div and CSS is below.

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {

  .main {
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 25%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 8;
  }
  .sidebar-offcanvas {
      position: fixed;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      height: 100%;
      z-index: 9;
      background-color: #f5f5f5;
      padding-top: 51px;
  }
  .main-content{
    padding: 0 40px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main-content">
</div>
```